# Bidi channel through compute

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

Flutter‘s compute allows to execute a callback inside a separate isolate and return a result.

Is there a similar function to open and keep a bidi channel that allows to send and receive messages between two isolates?

Comment: `IsolateChannel` - the docs say: *"A StreamChannel that communicates over a ReceivePort/SendPort pair, presumably with another isolate."*

Comment: Can you get those ports through Flutter’s compute or do I need to directly spawn?

Comment: you need to call `Isolate.spawn`

Comment: beware of Isolate in flutter, it can cause memory leak in your app, check it in profile mode.

Comment: *"Is there a similar function to open and keep a bidi channel that allows to send and receive messages between two isolates?"* - so `IsolateChannel` is not what you need? do you need simple one isolate<->isolate channel or you want to have multiple isolates with complex data flow?

Comment: I need to offload some data-heavy processing from the main thread.

Comment: if it is "one time job" use `compute()` - otherwise use `Isolate.spawn()` + `IsolateChannel` where you can submit multiple tasks (and get results) one be one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as comments by @pskink, the correct answer was to use `Isolate.spawn` and then an `IsolateChannel` to establish the BiDi-communication.